# Compare Boolean Row values across multiple Columns in Pandas using & / np.where() / np.any()

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, boolean, any

I have a dataframe that looks like:

```
   a A  a B  a C  a D  a E  a F  p A  p B  p C  p D  p E  p F
0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
2    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0
3    0    0    1    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0
4    0    0    0    1    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0
5    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
6    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0

df = pd.DataFrame({'p A':[0,0,0,0,0,0,1],'p B':[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],'p C':[0,0,1,0,0,0,0],'p D':[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],'p E':[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],'p F':[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],'a A':[0,1,0,0,0,0,0],'a B':[0,0,1,0,0,0,0],'a C':[0,0,0,1,0,0,0],'a D':[0,0,0,0,1,0,0],'a E':[0,0,0,0,0,1,0],'a F': [0,0,0,1,1,0,0]})
```

Note: This is a much simplified version of my actual data.

a stands for Actual; p stands for Predicted; A - F represent a series of labels

I want to write a query that, for each row in my dataframe, returns True when:  (all row values in "p columns" = 0 ) and (at least one row value in "a columns" =  1) i.e. for each row, p columns are fixed at 0 and at least 1 a column = 1.

Using answers to [Pandas Dataframe Find Rows Where all Columns Equal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22701799/pandas-dataframe-find-rows-where-all-columns-equal) and [Compare two columns using pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27474921/compare-two-columns-using-pandas)
I achieve this currently by using `&` and `np.any()`

```
((df.iloc[:,6] == 0) & (df.iloc[:,7] == 0) & (df.iloc[:,8] == 0) & (df.iloc[:,9] == 0) & (df.iloc[:,10] == 0) & (df.iloc[:,11] == 0) & df.iloc[:,0:6].any(axis = 1) )

>>
0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
4     True
5     True
6    False
dtype: bool
```

Is there a more succinct, readable way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `~` for invert boolean mask with [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) for select by position:

```
print (~df.iloc[:,6:11].any(1) & df.iloc[:,0:6].any(1))
0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
4     True
5     True
6    False
dtype: bool
```

Or use [`filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) for select by column names, [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) for check at least one `True` or [`all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) for check if all values are `True` per row.

Function [`eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) is for compare with `0`.

```
print (~df.filter(like='p').any(1) & df.filter(like='a').any(1))
0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
4     True
5     True
6    False
dtype: bool
```

---

```
print (df.filter(like='p').eq(0).all(1) & df.filter(like='a').any(1))
0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
4     True
5     True
6    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Which one to be the most "Pythonic" / most used in Pandas?

Comment: It is up to you, but I prefer more `filter` solutions, because more dynamic  - if some columns are added, solution stil work perfect.

Comment: Ok great. Thanks!